# Unequal letter spacing in 'listings'

Tags: spacing, listings

I am wondering why in the pdf of the example below the letters of the word "function" and the word "sum" seem to have different spacing. This somehow looks ugly.

Apart from that, I am wondering if someone has a "nicer-looking"/"easier-to-read" way of displaying `R` code with the `LaTeX` package `listings`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{% setup listings
    language=R,% set programming language
    basicstyle=\small,% basic font style
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,% keyword style
        commentstyle=\ttfamily\itshape,% comment style
    numbers=left,% display line numbers on the left side
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,% use small line numbers
    numbersep=10pt,% space between line numbers and code
    tabsize=3,% sizes of tabs
    showstringspaces=false,% do not replace spaces in strings by a certain character
    captionpos=b,% positioning of the caption below
        breaklines=true,% automatic line breaking
        escapeinside={(*}{*)},% escaping to LaTeX
        fancyvrb=true,% verbatim code is typset by listings
        extendedchars=false,% prohibit extended chars (chars of codes 128--255)
        literate={"}{{\texttt{"}}}1{<-}{{$\leftarrow$}}1{<<-}{{$\twoheadleftarrow$}}1
        {~}{{$\sim$}}1{<=}{{$\le$}}1{>=}{{$\ge$}}1{!=}{{$\neq$}}1{^}{{$^\wedge$}}1,% item to replace, text, length of chars
        alsoletter={.<-},% becomes a letter
        alsoother={$},% becomes other
        otherkeywords={!=, ~, $, *, \&, \%/\%, \%*\%, \%\%, <-, <<-, /},% other keywords
        deletekeywords={c}% remove keywords
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Just some text; see Line \ref{foo}.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A first example}, label=list:ex]
x <- c(1, 3, 2)
id <- function(x){
    x # just a dummy (*\label{foo}*)
}
3 <= 4
3 != 4
!TRUE
y <- "foo"
(pv <- sum(x*x^x))
y ~ x + a
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you specify either `columns=flexible`, or `columns=fullflexible` you will better results.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I played with it, either `columns=flexible` or `columns=fixed` with `basewidth=0.5` and spacing `2` (instead of `1`) for the `literate` entries looks good!

Comment: Does @PeterGrill's comment answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it solves it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `columns=flexible`, or `columns=fullflexible` options.  Refer to *Section 4.13 Column Alignment* of [the `listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) documentation.

Here is the output with `columns=flexible`:

[image]

Comment: The package documentation changed at some point. Now the relevant section number is 5.11, but section 2.11 specifically refers to the `flexible` and `fullflexible` options.