# How to write R formulas

Tags: formatting, documentation

The R language has formulas of the form (y ~ x) and (y ~ x + z). I have come to know that \tilde doesnt do the trick. How can I write these formulas in latex?

Comment: Are you looking for `$y\sim x$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\tilde
```

serves to put a tilde on top of something else.
For your purpose,

```
\sim
```

does the job.

Answer (score 2):

It may make more sense to use a verbatim mode to display R code.   For example the `fancyvrb` package allows you to define a delimiter for inline verbatim: e.g.

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
```

Then in your text you can use `| (y ~ x) |` directly. For larger chunks of code, the `listings` package is a good choice. Here's an example using it with R code:

- [Unequal letter spacing in 'listings'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79952/2693)